# how to assign a value to a object's property from GET request in angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, observable, subscription

In a service I have a GET request to an API. My goal is to subscribe to the observable and assign a value to each element's property of the array in the response.

**This is my service:**

```
export class Service {
 private readonly _sentinels = new BehaviorSubject<Sentinel[]>([]);

 readonly sentinels$ = this._sentinels.asObservable();

 public get sentinels(): Sentinel[] {
  return this._sentinels.getValue();
 }

 public set sentinels(val: Sentinel[]) {
  this._sentinels.next(val);
 }

 getSentinels(previousUrl?: string): Observable<Sentinel[]> {
  const obsSentinels$ = this.http.get<Sentinel[]>(`${baseUrl}/sentinels`);

  obsSentinels$.subscribe((sentinels) => {
    if (previousUrl && sentinels && sentinels.length > 0) {
     this.sentinels = this.setCameraStatusToTrue(sentinels);
    } else {
     this.sentinels = sentinels;
    }
  });
  return obsSentinels$;
 }


 setCameraStatusToTrue(sentinels: Sentinel[]) {
  sentinels.forEach((sentinel) => {
    sentinel.cameraStatus = true;
  });

  // here the cameraStatus is equal to true
  console.log('property');
  console.log(sentinels[0].cameraStatus);

  // here the cameraStatus in the object of the array is equal to undefined
  console.log('object into array');
  console.log(sentinels[0]);

  return sentinels;
 }
}
```

I don't really understand why in the result of `setCameraStatusToTrue()` the property `cameraStatus` of each object is `undefined`.

**Here is a pic of the console.log()**

[image: console.log() of result]

Comment: The code seems fine. Is there any code before  `console.log('object into array');`

Comment: there is no such variable `this.sentinels` in the service. Share all possible code

Comment: @navnath thanks for your answer. I edited the service as you made me notice adding ``sentinels`` property. Before ``console.log('object into array');`` there is no code

Comment: [match your code with me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aiafdc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservice.ts)

Comment: The response of my GET request is the same as yout fake datasource. I do not understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: If You generate same issue with your code on stackblitz, I could help you.